# Data throughput measuring solution using LabVIEW

Tags: ethernet, labview, throughput

I am using Ethernet to feed data into my LabVIEW system from a custom FPGA hardware. I wanted to know if there is some vi functionality or front panel functionality to display the throughput of the data received from the Ethernet port into the LabVIEW system or the PC.

Scouting through the [National Instruments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Instruments) forums, I did not find a solution for showing this statistic in LabVIEW.

Comment: "vi" in this context is probably for "[virtual instrument](https://labviewwiki.org/wiki/Virtual_Instrument)". A lot of the API functions has the prefix "vi", e.g. *"[viStatusDesc](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370131S-01/ni-visa/vistatusdesc/)"*.

Comment: Yes vi means virtual instrument here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This level of diagnostic is not something that is typically available from a LabVIEW function.

If you want to determine this data rate, you have a couple of options depending on your implementation:

1. *Monitor the data rate yourself*: Presumably you are catching and processing this data somewhere so write your own wrapper that counts the number of cycles and packets it is processing
2. *Look for a .NET implementation*: LabVIEW has fairly nice integration with Windows .NET libraries, and if you are able to find an appropriate library that implements this functionality you should be able to work with it.
3. Run a monitoring tool like [iPerf](https://iperf.fr/iperf-doc.php#3doc) via the command line periodically. This may not return as accurate data since it is external, but it should be reasonably straight-forward for testing.